# how to compare this "<null>" string?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, nsstring, nsurl

some times string showing  "null"  how can i check this error? 
if (imageUrl == (id)[NSNull null]) 
{

}

Comment: Is this iOS 7 specific ?

Comment: swift is not intotuced in ios 7

Comment: Is it a JSON issue?

Comment: `valueForKey:` is `KVC` method. It allows you to access a property using a string for its name so first debug it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik And it is not even `Swift`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   if ([imageUrl isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                  [_profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"]];


     }else{
        _profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"];


    }
```

Comment: if([imageUrl isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
  _profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"];
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *imageUrl= [ProfileArray valueForKey:@"photo"];

if ([imageUrl isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
    _profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"];
}
else
{                    
    [_profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"]];
}
_profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It should definitely work.

```
  NSString *imageUrl= [ProfileArray valueForKey:@"photo"];
    if ([imageUrl isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ) {
        _profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"];
    } else {
        [_profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
NSString *imageUrlString= [photoDict valueForKey:@"photo"];
if (imageUrl.length == 0) 
{
    _profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceHoldeImage"];
}
else
{
    _profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageUrlString];
}
```